# List comprehension from two sources

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Having this input:

```
a = (1,2,3)
b = 'something'
```

I want to create a list which will look like that:

```
['something', 1, 2, 3]
```

I tried to do:

```
[b, i for i in a]
```

But got a syntax error.

Note that, I'm looking for a **one line** solution out of curiosity.

Comment: You don't need a list comprehension: `[b, *a]`

Comment: You don't need a comprehension for that. It's `[b] + list(a)`

Answer (score 0):

If your variable 'a' will always be a tuple and 'b' will always be a string then you can try one thing...

```
a = (1,2,3)
b = 'something'

c = [b] + [i for i in a]
```

Comment: Much better answers were already given in the comments, so there is not much point in this answer.